# Google Sheets Timestamp on change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

What I'm trying to achieve is really simple however I'm super uncomfortable with the Google Sheet Script Editor.

I want the date in a certain cell updated whenever something changes on the active sheet.

That's what I got so far:

```
//Timestamp on change
function timestampOnChange() {
  getActiveCell().setValue(new Date());
}
```

However, even that already returns error messages :/

Comment: Please define which kind of changes you mean? Writing/ editing / deleting some content or changes to the spreadsheet's structure like e.g. inserting/deleting rows? It is important to specify which changes you mean, since the triggers to detect different changes are different.

Comment: Any of the above should update the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You need to create an [onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()) trigger of a particular
  function which will update a **specific** cell of the **active** sheet when the spreadsheet
  changes **content** or **structure**.
- The `updateCell()` function updates the value of **B1** with the current
  timestamp of the **active** sheet.
- I would advice you to update a **specific** sheet instead of the active
  sheet by using:

  ```
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ```

---

### Solution:

- In more detail, The `createOnChangeTrigger()` function will create
  the `onChange()` trigger that will execute `updateCell()` when there
  is a change in the content or structure of the spreadsheet file and in our case the active sheet.

  ```
  function createOnChangeTrigger(){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateCell")
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onChange()
    .create();
  }

  function updateCell(){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();  
    sh.getRange('B1').setValue(new Date());
  }
  ```

---

### Instructions:

Copy/Paste both functions in the script editor and execute `createOnChangeTrigger()` only once.

---

### References:

- [onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange())

Comment: Seems like a very nice solution, however it doesn't work for me. It doesn't return a error message either. When I execute it says "Loading..." for about 2 seconds, during that time when you hover over the field there is an error message "Error [new line] Loading data..."
After those 2 seconds it's just an empty cell without any hint on how to fix it...

Comment: @Robin33 share a copy of your sheet. I am not sure why you are getting the error. I can't reproduce it. Are you sure you only executed `createOnChangeTrigger()` ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZYbDKXKmOwMTs77SskYLi87zkThg6ihbozejUAV4jxU/edit#gid=0
the cell is A34

Comment: thanks for the help, really appreciate it (we communicated on the sheet, sheet will be read-only now

Answer (score 0):

From the question:

> ```
> //Timestamp on change
> function timestampOnChange() {
>   getActiveCell().setValue(new Date());
> }
> ```
>
> However, even that already returns error messages

The above code returns an error because theres isn't a built-in Google Apps Script function named `getActiveCell()`. To get the active cell you could use

```
SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell()
```

or

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
```

or if you use an edit event object (let say that it's a assigned to `e`) you could use `e.range`

It's worthy to not that if you use `setValue(new Date())` on the active cell what ever that was entered on that cell will be overwritten.

On Web Applications, a sister site of Stack Overflow, there a lot of Q/A about timestamps in Google Sheets, actually, there is tag for them ---> https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-timestamp. So far there are 102 questions with this tag.